# Winform app with SQL Server LocalDB getting unresponsive

Tags: c#, sql-server, combobox, localdb

I have created a C# Winforms app that has multiple comboboxes. For now some, comboboxes get 1000 items from a localDB table. It's little bit unresponsive.

I have used data-bound items to bind data to the comboboxes.

My question is: if more rows are added to localDB (eg: 2000 rows), will it get not respond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is too broad and unclear.  Please be specific how many comboboxes you have, what are the queries to the DB, whether the comboboxes are dependent on each other - for example, selecting an item in one combobox leading to repopulating others.  The latter can be a cause of great performance hits.

Further, a combo box with hundreds of records is a UX nightmare.  Better provide some searching / filtering facilities.

Comment: I didn't write any query myself. I just used Data Bound Items under ComboBox Tasks. I want this data to load combobox because of, I've to suggest name when user is typing.

Comment: Still not clear.  When a combo changes, do you update other combos?

Comment: Combobox changes when form loading. Also I'm inserting new record to DB. Then, comboboxes should update.